# Error fetching Trustpilot reviews using api

Tags: trustpilot

I intend to fetch the reviews using the trustilot api as documented in the api link below:
API: https://developers.trustpilot.com/business-units-api#business-unit-private-reviews

However, I have been getting the following error.

```
{"message":"Access to resource is forbidden","errorCode":1014,"correlationId":"4e77ga75-5fb7-62ab-a71b-0d01acd5cf29"}
```

I couldn't find much help in google.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

this API endpoint is only available to the paid customers and you have to have the appropriate API key for your account. In case you are a paying Trustpilot customer, pleas

Comment: Yes, it is for the paid account. I already have the API key. It was working until about 10 days back and then it stopped working.